# Override default javascript functionality with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I am trying to overwrite a JavaScript on change event in the below code with jQuery however I believe that the inline JavaScript is taking priority over the jQuery functionality declared. Essentially I am trying to have an AJAX version of my site which includes an additional JavaScript file. I need this functionality to still work without the additional AJAX version, but I am not sure as to whether I should include it in the main JavaScript file or leave it inline like it is right now. Any suggestions and information regarding them would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
<form action="/cityhall/villages/" method="post" name="submit_village">
    <select name="village" onchange="document.submit_village.submit();">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I am trying to use the jQuery Form Plugin to submit the posts to the PHP to handle the requests as follows:

```
var bank_load_options = { 
    target:        '#content',
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
    success:       showResponse
};
$('form.get_pages').livequery(function(){
    $(this).ajaxForm(bank_load_options);
    return false;
});
```

I modified the code as following:

```
<form action="/cityhall/villages/" method="post" id="submit_village" name="submit_village">
    <select name="village" class="get_pages" rel="submit_village">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
# main JavaScript
$('.get_pages').live('change',function(e){
    var submit_page = $(this).attr('rel');
    $("#"+submit_page).submit();
});

# ajax JavaScript
var bank_load_options = { 
    target:        '#content',
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
    success:       showResponse
};
$('.get_pages').live('change',function(){
    var submit_page = $(this).attr('rel');
    $("#"+submit_page).ajaxForm(get_pages_load_options);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

However now it only runs every other option when I change it.

Comment: Please show the code you are using (or trying to use) to "overwrite" the inline `onchange` attribute. Given that you are using jQuery anyway I'd suggest not using any JS in `onxyz` attributes even for your non-Ajax version.

Comment: If the functionality that is being set in `onchange` is moved to my main javascript file and the ajax file is declared afterwards, will it over write the functionality since they are in equal scope?

Comment: You should explicitly unbind the event then reattach it if you want to be certain that you've "overwritten" the old event. Make sure that this is done in the correct procedure though. It will depend heavily on how you're detecting and implementing the AJAX version...

Comment: The above code works, however I am finding that only every other option on the ajax version is running the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to have all your Javascript in one place (not one file specifically, but not half inline, half in a file), as such I would remove all inline Javascript.

This would also your help with priority issue as you can manage it all from the same location.

Comment: I did that and now I am only getting a run on every other option, any ideas? Check the above edits.

Answer (score 3):

Does your non-ajax version also have to be non-jQuery? If not then I also suggest (as @nnnnnn did) that you do away with the onxyz attributes and use jQuery throughout.

As other posters have suggested, inline events are inadvisable and should be done away with.

If your non-ajax version has to use onxyz then I'd suggest the following:

Setup a variable that will store whether this version is to be ajax or not (how you determine this is down to you and your app context):

var is_ajax = true;

Then if it is an ajax version try this:

```
$(function(){
    if(is_ajax){     
        //Unbind the change event from the village select box
        $('select[name="village"]').unbind('change');
        //As an extra measure, remove the onchange attribute
        $('select[name="village"]').removeAttr('onchange');
        //Re-bind the click event to execute your new ajax functionality
        $(document).on('change','select[name="village"]',function(){
            //Do ajax stuff for on-change event here
        });
    }
});
```

Because it sits in the document.ready function of jQuery this code should fire after the html dom (and it's associated onchange attributes) have been rendered. Therefore I'd imagine it'd effectively strip off the old event and re-bind a new one.

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/foxwisp/hdL5R/

If you can do away with the inline events then I imagine you'd want to do this in your initial javascript file:

```
$(document).on('change','select[name="village"]',function(){
    document.submit_village.submit();
});
```

And then the following in your ajax file to be included later:

```
$('select[name="village"]').removeAttr('onchange');
$(document).on('change','select[name="village"]',function(){
    //Do ajax stuff here
});
```

As long as both are in the same scope and timeframe such that they're executed one after the other then the above should work.

Comment: I have done away with the onxyz and replaced it with jQuery as the above shows. The main version works awesome, however the ajax version is only accepting every other option for change.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Yours may not have support for the .on() method. If you don't have the latest, perhaps try $('select[name="village"]').live('change',function(){

})

Comment: Try unbind() and die() on the select element before defining the ajax handler. 

$('.get_pages').die().unbind().live('change',function(){
    var submit_page = $(this).attr('rel');
    $("#"+submit_page).ajaxForm(get_pages_load_options);
    return false;
});

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/foxwisp/yKVnt/ this shows a simple implementation of it. Without the die and the unbind it'd execute both the old and new events. You can edit the fiddle to see. I am not sure what other factors in your app are causing it to only trigger on alternate options. Can you show your options code above?

Comment: Okay now I feel stupid! I just found an extra `$('form.get_pages').livequery(function(){$(this).ajaxForm(bank_load_options);return false;});` in the main file, which was throwing errors for some odd reason lol. Additionally it started working when I switched it from `.live()` to `.livequery()`. :P Thanks so much mate!

Answer (score 0):

Where you put your javascript is (largely) a choice of style.  Much like CSS, putting javascript in the page source (inline) or in the page head is good practice for writing your page initially but bad practice for production pages.

That being said, I am a bit confused as to why you would double up your onchange events.  Are you trying to use jQuery for the select element too?

I am not sure what the general behavior is for inline vs separate javascript, but I would venture to say that, similar to inline CSS, the in-page javascript will take precedence over an external file.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you could, in your AJAX version, forego the submit that has been triggered.

```
$('[name=submit_village]').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //...Maybe other AJAX code...
});
```

Comment: Also for something like this, it may be worth looking into a framework like backbone